# Angular nested Drag And Drop into another list

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I have a scenario, where I need to drop a feature into the respective item. So, here I am using angular-material for drag and drop but it is dropping feature outside of the item, I want to insert the feature inside the item.

Here is the sample: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cshhz-vsskhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html[enter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cshhz-vsskhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cshhz-vsskhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html)

What is the configuration I need to do?
Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to drag and drop first add this directive `cdkDropListGroup` to parent element.

After that change your array `done` to also include dropped items:

```
  done = [
    {
      name: "Apple",
      items: [] <-- here will be stored the dropped item
    },
```

after that move the droplist to be child of each `done` item.

```
  <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="item.items" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let it of item.items" cdkDrag>{{it}}</div>
  </div>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cshhz-ktl5rg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html). Don't forget to "open" the accordion to see the "droplist".